# Как вывести HTML-макет в управлеямых формах 1С 8.3?

Tags: 1с

**1С 8.3, Управляемые формы**

есть 1С-макет:

[image: 1с-макет]

Пытаюсь его показать пользователю:

[image: Код]

(пытался по-разному...)

При таком коде выходит вот такая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь ее разгуглить - не получается.

ЗЫ. я не 1с-ник, просто пытаюсь сделать мелкий фикс, чтобы пользователям была жизнь проще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь реквизит обработки `ПолеHTML` с типом `Форматируемый документ` и выкинь его на форму. Создай макет `HTML-документ`.

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ВывестиHTMLМакет(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка) 
    Вложения = Новый Структура; 
    ОтчетОбъект = РеквизитФормыВЗначение("Объект");
    Объект.ПолеHTML.УстановитьHTML(ОтчетОбъект.ПолучитьМакет("МакетСправкаКакПолучитьТоке н").ПолучитьТекст(), Вложения); 
КонецПроцедуры
```